# Getting Error while trying to create bpmn20.xml file dynamically

Tags: spring, activiti

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/activiti/bpmn/model/FlowElement

Service Class

```
    package com.activiti.deploy.service;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.activiti.bpmn.BpmnAutoLayout;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.converter.BpmnXMLConverter;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.BpmnModel;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.EndEvent;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.FormProperty;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.ParallelGateway;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.Process;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.ScriptTask;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.SequenceFlow;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.StartEvent;
    import org.activiti.bpmn.model.UserTask;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.activiti.deploy.model.ActivitiForm;

     @Service("ActivtiInterfaceService")
     @Transactional
     public class ActivitiInterfaceServiceImpl implements  ActivtiInterfaceService{



     public boolean deployinActiviti(ActivitiForm activitiForm) throws IOException{
    boolean deployed = false;


    BpmnModel model = new BpmnModel();
    Process process = new Process();
    model.addProcess(process);
    process.setId("my-process");
     process.setName("Qmplus test");
        process.addFlowElement(createStartEvent());
        process.addFlowElement(createUserTask("task1","First task","kermit",activitiForm));
        process.addFlowElement(createUserTask("task2","Second task","kermit",activitiForm));
        List<SequenceFlow> outgoing = new ArrayList<SequenceFlow>();
        outgoing.add(createSequenceFlow("task3","task4"));
        outgoing.add(createSequenceFlow("task3","task2"));
        process.addFlowElement(createParallelTask("task3","option task",outgoing));
        process.addFlowElement(createEndEvent());
        process.addFlowElement(createScriptTask("task4","script task","12343"));

        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("start","task1"));
        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task1","task3"));
        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task3","task2"));
        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task3","task4"));
        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task2","end"));
        process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task4","end"));
        // 2. Generate graphical information
        new BpmnAutoLayout(model).execute();
        /*DefaultHttpClient dhc = new DefaultHttpClient();

        dhc.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("kermit", "kermit"));

        HttpPost hp = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/deployment");


        hp.addHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------28617237579832" );
        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http"), basicAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

        MultipartEntity se = new MultipartEntity();
        byte[] xml = new BpmnXMLConverter().convertToXML(model);

        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
                  new FileOutputStream("target/test.bpmn20.xml"); 
        fileOuputStream.write(xml);
        fileOuputStream.close();


        File file = new File("target/test.bpmn20.xml");
        se.addPart("success", new StringBody("success", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        se.addPart("failure", new StringBody("failure", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
        se.addPart("deployment", fileBody);

        hp.setEntity(se);

       // HttpResponse processResponse = dhc.execute(hp,localcontext);

        //String data=IOUtils.toString(processResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        //System.out.println("reader"+data);

       // dhc.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); */

    return deployed;



}

protected UserTask createUserTask(String id, String name, String assignee, ActivitiForm activitiForm)
  {
    UserTask userTask = new UserTask();
    userTask.setName(name);
    userTask.setId(id);
    userTask.setAssignee(assignee);
    List<FormProperty> formProperties = new ArrayList<FormProperty>();
    formProperties.add(createFormProperty(activitiForm));
    userTask.setFormProperties(formProperties);
    return userTask;
  }

protected FormProperty createFormProperty(ActivitiForm activitiForm){
    FormProperty formproperty = new FormProperty();
    formproperty.setName(activitiForm.getTitle());
    formproperty.setType(activitiForm.getType());
    return formproperty;
}

  protected SequenceFlow createSequenceFlow(String from, String to)
  {
    SequenceFlow flow = new SequenceFlow();
    flow.setSourceRef(from);
    flow.setTargetRef(to);
    return flow;
  }

  protected ParallelGateway createParallelTask(String id, String name, List<SequenceFlow> outgoingFlows)
  {
    ParallelGateway p = new ParallelGateway();
    p.setId(id);
    p.setName(name);
    p.setOutgoingFlows(outgoingFlows);
    return p;

  }

  protected ScriptTask createScriptTask(String id, String name, String script)
  {
    ScriptTask st = new ScriptTask();
    st.setId(id);
    st.setScript("out.println(" + script + ")");
    st.setScriptFormat("groovy");
    st.setName(name);
    return st;
  }

  protected StartEvent createStartEvent()
  {
    StartEvent startEvent = new StartEvent();
    startEvent.setId("start");
    return startEvent;
  }

  protected EndEvent createEndEvent()
  {
    EndEvent endEvent = new EndEvent();
    endEvent.setId("end");
    return endEvent;
  } 
}
```

and pom.xml is the following:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringActiviti</groupId>
    <artifactId>ActivitiLearning</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ActivitiLearning Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
    <springFramework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springFramework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springFramework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springFramework.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
     <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
     <version>5.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
  <artifactId>activiti-bpmn-layout</artifactId>
  <version>5.17.0</version>
   </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
  <artifactId>activiti-bpmn-model</artifactId>
  <version>5.17.0</version>
  </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>ActivitiLearning</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
<finalName>ActivitiLearning</finalName>
</build>

      <repositories>
       <repository>
        <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
      <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
     </repositories>
    </project>
```

Comment: Where the error comes? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The class is from jar `org.activitiy:activiti-bpmn-model` that you have in your pom, so I think it is an deployment problem. If you use Eclipse, run Update Maven, Clean the project and Clean&Publish the Server. Important check that there is no compiler error in your project!